# understanding mongodb explain() output

Tags: mongodb, performance

I did read through https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/ to understand, before asking this query.

what do we look for in explain() output to determine if a given index is used to aid the sort portion of the query?

When run explain() on any query we see which index is used and some segment as follows

```
"winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "SORT",
                        "sortPattern" : {
                                "numReviews" : 1,
                                "rating" : -1
                        },
```

Is that sufficient to say the query is using a given index to do the SORT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of a `SORT` stage indicates that the query planner is sorting results in memory.

The results of the explain plan will [not include a `SORT` stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#sort-stage) if the index scan is being used to sort results.

Comment: The keyword "SORT" indicates if it was in-memory sort or not, but if "SORT" is not included then INDEX was used to do the actual sorting of the result-set?

Comment: Correct, but it's better to think of it as: "a sort was not needed to return results". For example, a query that did not include a `.sort()` would not have a SORT stage because no sorting was needed. The same thing applies for a query that can retrieve sorted results from an index. Let me know if it would help to update my response with examples.